# Remove element from array if contains some string

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove element from array based on predifened `$banned` array, i have play with array_diff but this is not what i need, array_diff is give me result.

```
$good = array("111","222","333","222 555","2223 555");
$banned = array("111","222");
$result = array_diff($good, $banned);
```

And result

```
Array
(
    [2] => 333
    [3] => 222 555
    [4] => 2223 555
)
```

But expected result should be

```
Array
(
    [2] => 333
    [4] => 2223 555
)
```

Comment: Then you will have to add "222 555" to banned array aswell .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your values in `$good` look like lists of values, you will most likely have to split them to compare them with the `$banned`.

So loop over `$good` and compare the exploded version with the `$banned` (using `array_intersect()` in this code), if there are no matching values, then add it to the results...

```
$good = array("111","222","333","222 555","2223 555");
$banned = array("111","222");
$result = [];
foreach ( $good as $entry ) {
    if ( array_intersect($banned, explode(" ", $entry)) === [] )    {
        $result[] = $entry;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what i need

Answer (score 0):

array_diff works correctly but in your case you need something like this:

```
$good = array("111","222","333","222 555","2223 555");
$banned = array("111","222");

foreach ($good as $el) {
    $ids = explode(' ', $el);
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        if (in_array($id, $banned)) break;
        $result[] = $el;
        break;
    }
}
``
```